# Comparing task completion using Graphs and Adjacency Matrices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to compare sequences of tasks completed using `Graph` and `AdjacencyMatrix`.  I have included an MWE for the readers' benefit.

Say that I have six steps to complete in the following directed "ideal sequence": `idealseq = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 4, 4 -> 6};`.  However, I end up doing something wrong and my "actual sequence" is `actualseq = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 4 -> 6};`.  In other words, I missed the task (directed edge) `3->4`, and `5->4`.

Clearly, the two `Graph` objects are different.

**Ideal sequence**

[image: Ideal Sequence]

**Actual sequence**

[image: Actual sequence]

When I convert the Adjacency Matrices of both graphs to ensure the same number of rows and columns, the indexes of adjacency are **wrong**.  In other words, the "**actual sequence**" should have the intersection of row 4 and column 6 highlighted (are adjacent). Instead row 4 and column 5 are shown to be adjancent **How should I ensure this?**

**Adjacency Matrix visualization of Ideal sequence**

[image]

**Adjacency Matrix visualization of actual sequence**

[image]

Comment: Provide the vertex lists (without gaps) explicitly: `AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[Range[6], {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 4, 4 -> 6}]]` and 
`AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[Range[6], {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 4 -> 6}]]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher What Black Magic is this?  Why didn't I think of that?!

Comment: Well, it is just too easy to forget that _Mathematica_ allows to use just anything as vertices so that integer vertices and their integer index need not always coincide. (I ran into this problem more than once...)

Comment: What I noticed (however) is if I use vertices that are strings instead of numbers, this method does not work.  i.e. `{"a" ->"b", "b"->"c", "c"->"d", "d"->"f","e"->"d"}` and `{"a" ->"b", "b"->"c", "d"->"f"}`.

Comment: Well, in this case it ought to be `AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[Alphabet[][[1 ;; 6]], {"a" -> "b", "b" -> "c", "c" -> "d", "d" -> "f", "e" -> "d"}]]` and 
`AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[Alphabet[][[1 ;; 6]], {"a" -> "b", "b" -> "c", "d" -> "f"}]]`... =)